# Android get current eastern standard time

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, android-date

I want to get the eastern standard time /EST current time but it keeps on showing my current time...
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z");
        TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(utc);
        Date now = gc.getTime();
        String strDateString = format.format(now);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Date` class is intended to reflect coordinated universal time (UTC), so it does not reflect timezone you use in `GregorianCalendar`. Also by default `SimpleDateFormat` uses system default timezone and if you want to override it you should do it explicitly:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z");
TimeZone la = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
format.setTimeZone(la);
```

Another option is to switch to Joda Time library:

```
DateTimeZone la = DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
DateTimeFormat.forPattern(dateTimeFormat).withZone(la).print(System.currentTimeMillis());
```